# namespace errors on classes when using JAXB and eclipse Juno

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipse-juno

I have some classes that model a filesystem, basically there is a base FileSystemEntry class and FileSystemDirectoryEntry, FileSystemFileEntry subclasses. All of these classes contain JAXB annotations.

All of this compiled without error using eclipse indigo using java 6 and 7. The classes continue to compile correctly using java 7 on our build boxes, but eclipse juno is highlighting the following error (domain name has been changed):

"Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace 'http://www.example.com/tree' and name 'fileSystemEntry' in this context"

The case of the class referenced in the error doesn't match the case of the actual class, unsure if that is related or not. The classes are annotated as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/tree")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class FileSystemEntry implements Iterable
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name="directory", namespace="http://www.example.com/tree")
public class FileSystemDirectoryEntry extends FileSystemEntry
```

The errors are highlighted for XmlRootElement and the class name in FileSystemEntry, and for the class name in FileSystemDirectoryEntry.

I can't tell if I am doing something wrong with JAXB and the juno build has improved to catch that, or if this is a problem with juno. I suspect the latter since our build machine handles these without issue.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.